# Where is weblogic.management.internal.EncrypedData located in weblogic?

Tags: oracle, weblogic

Hey I am trying to get a program compiled that requires the weblogic.management.internal.EncrypedData does anyone what jar file in weblogic has this function?

Answer (score 0):

This is found in `$Oracle_Middleware_HOME\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar`